# swift cant create a child in firebase database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to create a child in an empty firebase database using Swift, the code is running without any errors but I don't see the changes in the database. 
the code:

```
let ref = Database.database().reference()
ref.child("Branches")
```

Comment: You’re not setting any values into the database ref

Comment: I change the code to:
   let ref = Database.database().reference().child("Branches")
   let values = ["Email" : SEmailTextField.text]
   ref.updateChildValues(values as [AnyHashable : Any]) { (err, reference) in
                        print(err ?? "non")
                    }
but it's doesn't work

Comment: is the text attribute not empty? Have you configured Firebase on your project? What error does it prints?

Comment: Error Domain=com.firebase Code=1 "Permission denied" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Permission denied} https://coface-2148b.firebaseio.com/Branches 
this is the error

Comment: If you're having trouble with that, it should be approached as another question, otherwise this one will get messy.

Comment: Check security rules: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/

Comment: my firebase rules: 
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}

Comment: You shouldn't be getting that error if your rules are like that, make sure you configured everything. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/start

Comment: Also, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47984114/firebase-permission-denied

Comment: did you solve it?

Comment: yes, thank you! I did all the setups from the beginning and it worked

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not adding values to the database.

In Firebase, you create additional childs as soon as you set new values.

You can use `setValue` or `updateChildValues` to add values.

**Example:**

```
let ref = Database.database().reference().child("branches")

let values = ["any_key" : "any_value"]
ref.updateChildValues(values) { (err, reference) in
    // handle errors or anything related to completion block.
}
```

**Docs:** https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write

---

**Note:** Make sure you configured everything correctly: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/start

Comment: Is it not possible to create a child without input? I can create one online on Firebase but not with coding?

Answer (score 1):

It's depend on your database structure let suppose you create

```
{ 
      "users": {
        "uid": userID,
            "username": "string"
      }
}
```

this time data then you can get it as you mention in your question

```
var ref: DatabaseReference!
ref = Database.database().reference()
self.ref.child("users").child(user.uid).setValue(["username": username])
```

- In this can be some mistake but you have to understand concept,